# How do I change the default Django engine database from db.sqlite3 to a mysql database populated with test data?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

This is my first time doing this so please bear with me.

**What I am trying to do:**

Change the 'DATABASES' setting in my 'settings.py' from the 'ENGINE: 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' to a pre-populated mysql database with test username data.

More specifically, 
I want to change the default django database from db.sqlite to a mysql database. The mysql database I am trying to use instead of the default already has user information which I want to use and test.

**What I have done so far:**

I have already authenticated a couple of users(using the default db.sqlite3) to be able to add blog posts on my website which is currently hosted on a domain.

**What I am not sure about:**

Was changing the settings.py DATABASE default something I should have done at the very beginning ?? Or can I change it at any time without risking previously made changes?

Does replacing the DATABASE default settings with something like the one below affect already existing user data ??

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': '{{projectName}}',
'USER': 'root',
'PASSWORD': 'root',
'HOST': 'localhost',
'PORT': '3306',
}
}
```

What is the proper way to go about this given that I already have my blog website up and running on a domain?

Comment: You will need to dump the data from your sqlite db and import it into the new MySQL one.

Answer (score 0):

> Was changing the settings.py DATABASE default something I should have done at the very beginning

Yes. Each database is a different entity. Say that you have a hose and a red bucket (SQlite) and a blue bucket (MySQL).

You can't switch your hose from red to blue and expect the water you have already poured to transfer. Yes, you should have done that from the beginning.

> Does replacing the DATABASE default settings with something like the one below affect already existing user data ??

Yes

> What is the proper way to go about this given that I already have my blog website up and running on a domain?

Migrate the data over. Here is how you do this:

1. Run `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json`
2. Switch to your MySQL database settings.
3. Run `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`

This may or may not work depending on your data, but it will get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will give that a shot!